# Variable might not have been initialized?

Tags: java, string, types, methods

I have the following code for a conversion program:

```
private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int type, value;
    double conversion;
    String output;

    type = Integer.parseInt(conversionchoiceInput.getText());
    value = Integer.parseInt(valueInput.getText());

    if (type == 1)
    {
    conversion = inchesToCentimetres(value);
    output = value + " inches = " + Math.round(conversion) + " centimetres";
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {

    }
    else if (type == 3)
    {

    }
    else if (type == 4)
    {

    }
    outputLabel.setText(output); 
}
```

It says "variable output might not have been initiaized" when I already have?

Thanks!

Comment: When you write `String output;` you're _declaring_ `output`. When you write `String output = "";` (or any value. "" is just an example) you're _initialising_ it.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to split declaration and initialization of variables (type, value). Declare them on initialization, if possible. Only split them if necessary (before a try/catch-block, for instance).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `output` needs to be initialised no matter what execution path the program takes.  It is only initialised in the `if` path.  Therefore, you need to give it a default value at the start (of empty string or something) or set it in all branches.

```
String output = "";
```

or

```
if (type == 1)
{
    conversion = inchesToCentimetres(value);
    output = value + " inches = " + Math.round(conversion) + " centimetres";
}
else if (type == 2)
{
    output = "";
}
else if (type == 3)
{
    output = "";
}
else if (type == 4)
{
    output = "";
}
```

Naturally, the first option is the best.

Comment: you can also initialize it with the most common value, that way you don't have to check for the most common option in the if statement, just check the others.

Answer (score 0):

If type != 1, then output isn't initialized. And even if you give output a value in each of the if branches (1, 2, 3, 4) output might not have been initialized, as if type < 1 or > 4 it still has no value.

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared the variable there which is different from initializing it.